# How to convert DataStream[Row] into Table?

Tags: apache-flink

For this case, java environment support method `returns()` to specify type information.
But int scala environment `,org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream` does't have returns().
How to convert a scala DataStream[Row] into a scala Table?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [table API documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/common.html#row), you can use

```
// get a TableEnvironment
val tableEnv: StreamTableEnvironment = ... // see "Create a TableEnvironment" section

// DataStream of Row with two fields "name" and "age" specified in `RowTypeInfo`
val stream: DataStream[Row] = ...

// convert DataStream into Table with default field names "name", "age"
val table: Table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(stream)
```